# ESXi 5.5 missing VMware Tools ISOs

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-tools

The VMware Tools ISO's in my new ESXi 5.5 installation are missing. Where can I download them from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the tools link for ESXi 5.5](http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.5/index.html) Choose your OS and download ISO.

[Reference this VMware KB Article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1036810)